# Replace a character before a specific word with an @

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel file consisting of 900 email addresses but instead of an @ they contain decimal points. For example:

```
dan.shan.google.com
karen.karr.google.com
barry.shan.google.com
```

They are all using the same domain (google) though which is fine. What I need to be able to do is to replace just the decimal before "google.com" with an @ instead.

How would I go about doing that without having to do all 900 manually?

Thanks

Comment: How about search and replace?

Comment: The problem with that is I only want the decimal point before "google.com" replaced. Not all of them in each email

Comment: Try to replace all occurence of  `.google` with `@google` for example...?

Comment: @groenhen - What about Harry Google's email account?

Comment: @Jeeped: That reminds me of an old joke about Chuck Norris email address :) Seriously now: what so hard to fix it? Replace all `.google.com` with `@google.com`...

Answer (score 1):

Since `.google.com` is always the end of the string, you can take the `LEN(address)-len(".google.com")` characters from the beginning, then concatenate `@google.com` to them.

The equations:

[image]

The results:

[image]

---

Alternatively, as [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955417/replace-a-character-before-a-specific-word-with-an/42955569#comment73006454_42955569) had kindly pointed out, you can do:

```
= REPLACE(A4, LEN(A4)-10, 1, "@")
```

Comment: @Jeeped Nor of commenting.

Comment: `=substitute(a2, ".google.com", "@google.com")` maybe...?

Comment: @Jeeped - What about Harry Google Com's email account?

Comment: LOL - that would require `=replace(a2, len(a2)-10, 1, "@")`

Answer (score 0):

Select the Column. Press `crtl+F`. In find what text box type : .google.com and in replace with @google.com and click on replace all.

[image]

Comment: This would fail if for some reason there's more than one ".google.com" in a single entry.